# How can I skip chained promises resulting in exceptions?

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, promise

I have multiple apis to hit.

E.g

```
callApis = async function () {

  try {

    var apis = ["apiWithSucess1", "apiWithException", "apiWithSucess1"];

    var response = "";

    for(var i = 0; i < apis.length; i++){

      const apiResponse = await httpRequest.get(apis[i]).promise(); 

      response+=apiResponse.data;
    }

    return response;
  } 
  catch (err) {
    console.log("Exception => ", err);
  }
};

callApis().then(function(result){

  console.dir(result);
  
}).catch(function(err) {
  
  console.log(err); 
});
```

Now when I call this and if there is some api in array that throws exception, it crashes all the process. I want the api with exception to be skipped.

Comment: Wrap the individual calls in `try`/`catch`...

Comment: You only need to wrap the line of code that will throw. You can `continue` in the error handler.

Comment: @RandyCasburn but would that resume if some api throws exception in start or middle?

Comment: It would do [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert a `try`/`catch` clause:

```
...
let apiResponse
for(var i = 0; i < apis.length; i++){
  try {
    apiResponse = await httpRequest.get(apis[i]).promise(); 
  catch (error) {
     console.error(error)
     continue
  }
  response+=apiResponse.data;
}
...
```

Anything in a `try` clause will run normally, unless an exception/error is thrown. In that case, it ends up in the `catch` clause, where one can handle the issue. I've simply placed a `continue` statement there so you only get good responses, though you can also add a `null` into the response, and then `continue`, so that your response array is ordered.

Comment: The one addition I'd suggest is to log the error.  Catching, but not logging errors can lead to difficult debugging when something isn't working, but nothing is logging.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch errors with `try`/`catch` as in [Michal Burgunder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70252192/1426891), but if it is not important that the APIs are chained or otherwise called in sequence, then you have the opportunity to call them in parallel to make the process faster. This would entail calling [`Promise.allSettled()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) (or [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), if you mute errors with `.promise().catch(() => "")`).

In conventional syntax:

```js
callApis = /* no longer async */ function () {
  var apis = ["apiWithSuccess1", "apiWithException", "apiWithSuccess1"];
  // For each API, call promise() and mute errors with catch().
  // Call Promise.all to wait for all results in parallel.
  return Promise.all(apis.map(x => httpRequest.get(x).promise().catch(() => "")))
      // Join the results array as a string with no separators.
      .then(arrayOfStrings => arrayOfStrings.join(""))
      // If any of the above steps fails, log to console and return undefined.
      .catch(err => { console.log("Exception => ", err); });
}
```

In your `async`/`await` syntax, aside from the exception-muting `catch` call in the `map`:

```
callApis = async function () {
  try {
    var apis = ["apiWithSuccess1", "apiWithException", "apiWithSuccess1"];
    // For each API, call promise() and mute errors with catch().
    // Call Promise.all to wait for all results in parallel.
    var responseArray = await Promise.all(apis.map(
        x => httpRequest.get(x).promise().catch(() => "")));
    // Join the results array as a string with no separators.
    return responseArray.join(""));
  } 
  catch (err) {
    console.log("Exception => ", err);
  }
}
```